# Google Sheet App Script Protect Range & Allow Editors Based on Email But Exclude Few Columns From Edit Rights

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using below script to protect data upto last row on opening the sheet. The script will add protection on the range and will allow the sheet owner and email id specified in the code to edit the protected range. The script performs its work, however, I want to update below in the script.

E.g. There are 5 columns in the sheet and data upto row no. 100, so on opening the sheet the script will protect all the columns upto row no. 100, only the sheet owner and the specified email id will be allowed to edit this protected range. I want a permanent protection on Col A & Col D so in this case the specific email id covered in the script will get access to protected range but excluding column A & col D.

```
function installedOnOpen(e) {
const editors = ["###"]; // Added: Please set the email addresses you want to give 
the permission as the editor.

const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to protect.
const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => 
sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
if (sheets.length == 0) return;
sheets.forEach(s => {
const p = s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
if (p.length > 0) {
  p.forEach(pp => pp.remove());
}
const lastRow = s.getLastRow();
if (lastRow != 0) {
  const newProtect = s.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, s.getMaxColumns()).protect();
  newProtect.removeEditors(newProtect.getEditors());
  newProtect.addEditors(editors); // Added
  if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);
}
});
}
```

Any help on above will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to protect the rows from 1st row to the last row. In this case, you want to give the edit permission to the specific user. And, for the specific columns, you don't want to make all users edit.
- Added: `I want these columns to be protected in full i.e. entire column should be protected.`

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script 1:

Please install OnOpen trigger to the function. When you reopen the Spreadsheet, the script is automatically run.

```js
function installedOnOpen(e) {
  const editors = ["###"]; // Added: Please set the email addresses you want to give the permission as the editor.
  const permanentProtectedColumns = [1, 4]; // Added: Please set the permanent protected columns.

  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to protect.
  const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
  if (sheets.length == 0) return;
  sheets.forEach(s => {
    const p = s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    if (p.length > 0) {
      p.forEach(pp => pp.remove());
    }
    const lastRow = s.getLastRow();
    if (lastRow != 0) {
      const newProtect = s.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, s.getMaxColumns()).protect();
      newProtect.removeEditors(newProtect.getEditors());
      newProtect.addEditors(editors);
      if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);

      // I added below script.
      const maxRow = s.getMaxRows();
      permanentProtectedColumns.forEach(r => {
        const pp = s.getRange(1, r, maxRow).protect();
        pp.removeEditors(pp.getEditors());
        if (pp.canDomainEdit()) pp.setDomainEdit(false);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the 1st row to the last row is protected. In this case, the owner and specific users can edit the protected ranges. But, the columns of `const permanentProtectedColumns = [1, 4];` (in this case, columns "A" and "D") can be edited by only the owner.

#### Modified script 2:

I think that the above modified script can be used. But, in your situation, the process cost might be high a little. So, if you want to reduce the process cost, how about using Sheets API as follows?

In this case, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function installedOnOpen(e) {
  const editors = ["###"]; // Added: Please set the email addresses you want to give the permission as the editor.
  const permanentProtectedColumns = [1, 4]; // Added: Please set the permanent protected columns.
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to protect.

  const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
  if (sheets.length == 0) return;
  const id = e.source.getId();
  const obj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(id, { ranges: sheets.map(s => s.getSheetName()), fields: "sheets(protectedRanges)" }).sheets;
  const protectedIds = obj.flatMap(({ protectedRanges }) => protectedRanges ? protectedRanges.map(({ protectedRangeId }) => protectedRangeId) : []);
  const requests1 = [];
  if (protectedIds.length > 0) {
    protectedIds.forEach(s => requests1.push({ deleteProtectedRange: { protectedRangeId: s } }));
  }
  const owner = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  const requests2 = sheets.map(s => {
    const sheetId = s.getSheetId();
    const lastRow = s.getLastRow();
    const maxCol = s.getMaxColumns();
    return { addProtectedRange: { protectedRange: { range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: 0, endRowIndex: lastRow, startColumnIndex: 0, endColumnIndex: maxCol }, editors: { domainUsersCanEdit: false, users: [owner, ...editors] } } } };
  });
  const requests3 = sheets.flatMap(s => {
    const sheetId = s.getSheetId();
    const maxRow = s.getMaxRows();
    return permanentProtectedColumns.map(t => ({ addProtectedRange: { protectedRange: { range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: 0, endRowIndex: maxRow, startColumnIndex: t - 1, endColumnIndex: t }, editors: { domainUsersCanEdit: false, users: [owner] } } } }));
  });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: [...requests1, ...requests2, ...requests3] }, id);
}
```

- In this sample script, the same result with the above script is obtained.

Comment: @ Tanaike Thanks for the solution, it works as expected except below, permanentProtectedColumns = [1, 4] protects column 1 and 4 only till the last row having data, I want these columns to be protected in full i.e. entire column should be protected.

Comment: @Edyphant Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. I couldn't notice `I want these columns to be protected in full i.e. entire column should be protected.`. So, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: @ Tanaike thanks for your reply, I want to lock all rows of permanentProtectedColumns = [1, 4].

Comment: @Edyphant Thank you for replying. About `I want to lock all rows of permanentProtectedColumns = [1, 4].`, when I tested my proposed script, all rows of columns "A" and "D" are protected. When you tested my sample script, what result did you obtain? If I misunderstood your request, I apologize.

Comment: @ Tanaike Tanks for your reply.... when I run the script protection in column A and D is applied till the last row having data e.g. if data is upto row no. 150 then protection is applied till row no. 150. So protection 1 will be A1:V150, protection 2 will be A1:A150 and protection 3 will be D1:D150. I want protection 2 as A:A and protection 2 as D:D.

Comment: @Edyphant Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unofrtunately, I cannot unedrstand your reply. So, in order to correctly understand your reply, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @ Tanaike ..... there was some error in copy and paste of the script at my end but after again copying and pasting the script  it gives the correct result and locks column 1 and 4 all rows ....sorry for the inconvenience... and thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: as regards the second option i.e. using the sheets API I enabled the Sheets API and then tried to run the code but its not giving the result, I am sharing the link of the sheet for your reference....https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bIZEQ-xhcaf4UZTs3ZVwcFo8z23HSRzNihSweez4rf8/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Edyphant Thank you for replying. I'm glad my 1st script resolved your question. About `as regards the second option i.e. using the sheets API I enabled the Sheets API and then tried to run the code but its not giving the result,`, I cannot understand the detailed situation. But, when I tested my proposed 2nd script using your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurs. All rows of the columns 1 and 4 are protected. And, the 1st row to the last row of other columns are protected. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `but its not giving the result`.