# Lock row to all editors based on value in one cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KZUN_8k5mJ9BGG0insAhRGbKuad6j5pt78gBihMKdy8/edit?usp=sharing

I wanted that once a person fill any row and select "Submit" in column J, the entire row should be locked for the editor and the excess should only be given to me and one more person. Following is the code:

```
function LockRow(e){
  let range = e.range;
  let row = range.getRow();  
  let col = range.getColumn(); 
  let value = e.value;
  let sheet = range.getSheet(); 
  const editors = ["email"]

  if(col == 11 && row >= 3 && value == "Submit"){ 
    let lock_range = `A${row}:K${row}`; 
    let protection = sheet.getRange(lock_range).protect() 
      .setDescription(`Lock ${row}`)  
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors())
    newProtect.addEditors(editors); 
  }
  else if(col == 11 && row >= 3 && value == "Edit" & ""){ 
    var protectedRange = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); 
    for (var i = 0; i < protectedRange.length; i++)  { 
      if (protectedRange[i].getDescription() == `Lock ${row}`) { 
        protectedRange[i].remove(); 
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that after selecting submit in column J the row is getting locked but the excess to edit is only with the owner (i.e. me) of the sheet and is not getting shared with the mentioned email.

Updated code

```
   function LockRow(e){
  let range = e.range;
  let row = range.getRow();  
  let col = range.getColumn(); 
  let value = e.value;
  let sheet = range.getSheet();
  const editors = ["gmail"];

  if(col == 11 && row >= 3 && value == "Submit"){ 
    let lock_range = `A${row}:K${row}`; 
    let protection = sheet.getRange(lock_range).protect() 
      .setDescription(`Lock ${row}`)  
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    newprotect.addEditors(editors); 
  }
  else if(col == 11 && row >= 3 && value == "Edit"){ 
    var protectedRange = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); 
    for (var i = 0; i < protectedRange.length; i++)  { 
      if (protectedRange[i].getDescription() == `Lock ${row}`) { 
        protectedRange[i].remove(); 
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Does this topic help [Google Sheet App Script Protect Range & Allow Editors Based on Email But Exclude Few Columns From Edit Rights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72669124/1330560)

Comment: It is a sound solution however, i am looking to use "onedit" trigger, as i want the editor to  submit when he completes the entry. In the referred solution it is locking all rows once a sheet is reopened.

Comment: I respectfully suggest that you need to look beyond the definition of the protected range  and the specific trigger, and consider how you can adapt the process for identifying and enabling continued editing rights for certain editors. That is what you are trying to, isn't it?

Comment: I have updated the code and changed function from "onedit" to "lockrow" and assigned separate trigger. Now the locked row's access is only with owner, however i want to give excess to one more person. I have added the email of other person but still the excess is getting restricted to only owner of the sheet

Comment: Sounds like some progress... Have you added `const editors = ["###"];` (the email addresses of the editors to have access, and then `newProtect.addEditors(editors);`. In any event, you need to share your revised code (edit your question and show an "Update" at the bottom) so we can see the actual script rather than try and interpret your description.

Comment: I made the suggested changes. However the excess is still with owner only

Comment: As a matter of interest, how long do you excect that this protection should last?

Comment: Delete: `newprotect.addEditors(editors);` and replace with: `protection.addEditors(editors);`